# Is it possible to create adapter dynamically from users app using worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-studio

I'm developing a RSS feed worklight application which shows some categories of feeds like  education, entertainment, sports, technology, business etc.

Upon selecting a category I'm showing the list of websites names from where i'm showing the feeds. I've created many adapters i.e for each individual website of each category, i had created adapter and configuring domain name and path.

Q: Is it possible to show the feeds from a website for which i've not created adapter. is it possible to create adapter dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTTP adapter's connectivity policy section, you specify the backend server the adapter will be sending its request to.

It is not possible to change this during runtime. So the answer is no.

Comment: Thank you..
 if user wants to get feeds from a new domain, for which i had not created adapter or any implementation..then to provide that feature. ?

Comment: You don't have to use adapters. You can use AJAX, but then you lose all the Worklight features surrounding adapters, like security, etc.